# How to get the running threads in my App only

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to get all the active/running threads in the App. I wrote the below posted code, and I got the below posted results.
Actually, none of the threads in the posted output belong to my App except

```
07-10 15:36:48.621 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[IntentService[GcmIntentService],5,main]
```

1) what does number 5 indicates?

2)it seems that 'getAllStackTraces' retrieves all the active threads system-wide, but how can I get the threads that are only running in my App?

**code**:

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
Thread thread = null;
for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++) {
    thread = threadArray[i];
    Log.d(TAG, "thread.toString():" + thread.toString());
}
```

**output**:

```
07-10 15:36:48.621 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[IntentService[GcmIntentService],5,main]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[FinalizerWatchdogDaemon,5,system]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[Timer-0,5,main]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[RenderThread,5,main]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[ReferenceQueueDaemon,5,system]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[FinalizerDaemon,5,system]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[Binder_3,5,main]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[main,5,main]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[Signal Catcher,5,system]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[Binder_1,5,main]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[Binder_2,5,main]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[GCDaemon,5,system]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
07-10 15:36:48.622 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[JDWP,5,system]
07-10 15:36:48.623 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[HeapTrimmerDaemon,5,system]
07-10 15:36:48.623 19333-19624/eu.men.m2sapp D/GcmIntentService: thread.toString():Thread[Thread-52709,5,main]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Actually, none of the threads in the posted output belong to my App

All of those threads belong to your app's process. Most come from the framework, instead of your code.

> it seems that 'getAllStackTraces' retrieves all the active threads system-wide

No, it retrieves the threads in your process.

> how can I get the threads that are only running in my App?

You already are.

> what does number 5 indicates?

I believe that is the thread priority.

Comment: plus1. would you please tell me how to get the threads that started from my code only?

Comment: @user2121: Keep track of them when you start them. From what I can see, the framework started all of your threads, unless you decided to create  your own class named `IntentService`.

Comment: would you please tell me how did you know that I started my thread from IntentService?ok, we know in advance that IntentService is Android class, but aside from IntentService how one should know if a thread started from a specific class? maybe because there is '[]' square brackets after the class name?

Comment: @user2121: "would you please tell me how did you know that I started my thread from IntentService?" -- `Thread[IntentService[GcmIntentService],5,main]` suggests that an `IntentService` was involved. I think that comes from `setName()`, or the `Thread` constructor taking a `String` parameter.

Comment: ok fine, then according to what you stated, 'Thread[Timer-0,5,main]' which class started 'Timer-0', because 'Timer-0' is not a class name i think?!

Comment: @user2121: Whether `Timer` names its threads `Timer-...`, or whether that is from something else, I cannot say.